# How can I create a hover drop down action link on _layout.cshmtl using MVC3 Razor

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a navigation menu that is displayed horizontally like this.

```
                <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About_Us", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("What We Do", "What_We_Do", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQ's", "Answers_To_Questions", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Deed Transfer Gurantee's", "Deed_Transfer_Guarantee", "Home")
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Power Point", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Get Help", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mortgage Cancellation", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I am looking for a way to create a drop down link to be visible only when the specific link is moused over. I need the Deed_Transfer_Guarantee ActionLink to display another ActionLink when the Deed_Transfer_Guarantee is hovered over. I have not been able to find a clear example of this yet. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're trying to make something appear when you hover, this question isn't really about MVC, C# or Razor - you should be looking at the HTML/CSS.  As an aside, I suggest you [read this comic](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) jquery sample out. All you've got to do is replace "`<span> ***</span>` " with a hyper link

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help:

```
$("#menu li a").each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $("<a></a>").html($this.html()).attr("href",$this.attr("href")).addClass("dropdown").slideUp(0).appendTo($this);
}).hover(function(){
    $("a",$(this)).slideDown(500);        
}
,function(){
     $("a",$(this)).slideUp(500);      
});
```

and then u need some css:

```
#menu li>a{position:relative;}
#menu li a a.dropdown {position:absolute;left:0px;top:100%;}
```

i think this can do the work.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. I'll have to work with it a little but it's definitely what I need to get going in the right direction. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think using a new li tag will give you a drop down as opposed to a "slide out" in the jquery example online. This is essentially Bumble Bee's answer.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Deed Transfer Gurantee's").hover(function(){
 $(this).append($('<li>@Html.ActionLink(@*whatever parameters you need*@)</li>'));
    });
 });
</script>
```